# Adding button that adds custom sheet in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working on a Google Sheet to perform analysis on the cyclomatic complexities of the software under test. There's multiple projects, and I've been assigned to, and completed analysis on, one of them. I wish to extend this Spreadsheet, such that, when a user hits "Add Sheet" button, they can create a sheet ready for data insertion and analysis.

**The format of the sheet**

Thus far, looks like this: 
[image]
...
[image]

**Strategy**

I know that it's possible (as I have done from experience!) to create a container-bound Google Script to create Sheets. I just don't know how to create a button to do so, let alone at the Spreadsheet level.

**Business Requirements**

- The header row should be copied over and formatted
- Custom cells (in the "Already unit-tested?" column) should be insertable, and the "FALSE" one should be inserted on row creation
- formulae for average complexity,standard deviation,median complexity,number of files computations should be inserted on spreadsheet creation and update upon row creation/state change of rows

I'm not sure the way to go about all this, let alone the score of this user story.

Comment: can you share the spreadsheet, I'll chat with you and try to fin  solution.

Comment: Your function will need to use `SpreadsheetApp` (most things) and `DriveApp` (move the spreadsheet to the correct Google Drive folder). You can go about this in many ways (e.g. copy a template sheet, write values and formats as defined in the script, etc.) so this question is too broad. Note that it isn't clear if you also want to copy the script that does this into the new workbook, in which case you will run into a code duplication **nightmare** and should instead use a library or add-on to house the script.

Comment: @JSmith The spreadsheet is under the company's GSuite account, thus I cannot share it directly. I'll have to wait til I'm home to create a shareable version of it

Comment: @MikeWarren ok tell me

Comment: @JSmith Here's a shareable copy of the spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fQ0e4jnY9v-QS55_Vv85TPLjXwj--VwUMnay4zbb9Pc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @MikeWarren sended you a request for editing

Answer (score 1):

I’d put the button on a sidebar and in that case it can be any kind of html button you wish.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try insert a menu in my spreadsheet, [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus) you'll find custom menu documentation.

just create a function like `newSheet()` and trigger it when button is pressed.

for the first row and the format you can use `srcRange.copyTo(destRange)`.

use a drop-down list for the "Already unit-tested?" column using [data validation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation)

and for the formulas just type in the formula and use `range.setValues()`.